# Different Image button fit Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

For the Image button, the ios the image seems to works fine

[image]

However, when I run in the andriod the image is too big.

[image]

Is there any way to make the andriod version fit nicely without messing up the iphone one?

Comment: Change the image resolution.

Comment: show us some code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the resolution of the images you are putting in the Android project folder.